FreeBSD process group membership not respected
Here's what I do: I let Exim deliver an email using a pipe transport for a dovecot-lda process. This process is running as user/group jdoe:jdoe. (I checked this twice using a self-written wrapper and truss as well.) The message gets delivered correctly; yet I see a message:
dovecot_lda transport output: lda(jdoe): Error: net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: Permission denied

But it's sure that jdoe has the required permissions by group wheel membership:
# ls -l /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer
srw-rw----  1 dovecot wheel 0  7 Sep. 22:13 /var/run/dovecot/stats-writer
# id jdoe
uid=1001(jdoe) gid=1001(jdoe) groups=1001(jdoe),0(wheel),...

So what is going on here?
When I change the process ownership in the Exim transport configuration, the warning disappears but the delivery fails. When I change the socket user to jdoe in the Dovecot stats service, the problem still isn't solved for other users.
What else can I try?
The exim transport configuration is:
dovecot_lda:
  driver = pipe
  command = /usr/bin/truss -s 1024 -o /tmp/dovecot.truss -f /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d "${lookup{$local_part}dsearch{/usr/local/misc/mail}}"
  user = $local_part
  group = $local_part
  ...
  temp_errors = 64 : 69 : 70: 71 : 72 : 73 : 74 : 75 : 78


What starts this dovecot-lda process? Does it just inherit the uid:gid from its parent, or does the starter explicitly set its uid:gid to jdoe?

As far as I can see Exikm forks, sets uid:gid and then execs to Dovecot (respectively truss).


As far as I can see Exikm forks, sets uid:gid and then execs to Dovecot

You will probably need to set the initgroups option on the transport to tell Exim that it also needs to set the supplementary group list.
The kernel does not automatically infer them from the primary UID – it is up to Exim to set both the primary UID:GID and supplementary GIDs.
(And there is no single "become user X" function that software could use, so they have to assemble their own UID/GID switching code out of multiple APIs, with all the inconsistencies that entails; e.g. skipping the initgroups() call "because performance" or something.)

Bingo! Exactly what I searched for. Thanks a lot!
